# Cocoapods not setting search paths correctly

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I opened an iOS (Swift) project today I hadn't touched for a while and it wouldn't build. The first import statement for a Cocoapods framework was throwing a `No such module` compile error in Xcode. Changing the order of import statements made the error throw on whichever was the first external dependency in my import list.

I fixed this by adding each of my Cocoapods to `Framework Search Paths` in my project's main target (it has a few targets, including tests, a share extension, and a framework of shared code for the app and extension). These search paths were empty and now look like this:

[image: screenshot of framework search paths]

After doing that the project built fine, but now I'm getting this `SIGABRT` error every time I try to run the app (both on simulator and device):

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CocoaLumberjack.framework/CocoaLumberjack
  Referenced from: [path removed]
  Reason: image not found
```

My guess is this is to do with CocoaLumberjack needing to be linked somewhere else/some other way because of its macros but I don't really know.

I've also tried running `pod install`, cleaning the build folder and deleting derived data, and running `pod deintegrate` + `pod install` with no success.

Is it possible to get Cocoapods to automatically set up my search paths correctly so I don't have these issues? Or is there a manual step I'm missing or have done wrong perhaps?

Edited to add my Podfile:

```rb
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# This is my shared framework, used by both my app and share extension
target 'XXXShared' do
    pod 'SnapKit', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 7.0'
    pod 'Reveal-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']
    pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
    pod 'APESuperHUD', :git => 'https://github.com/apegroup/APESuperHUD.git'
    pod 'WSTagsField', '~> 3.1'
    pod 'Cache', '~> 4.2'
    pod 'TableKit', '~> 2.5'
    pod 'GRDB.swift', '~> 3.2'
    pod 'PromiseKit', '~> 6.0'
    pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 3.0.1'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
    pod 'CollectionKit'
    pod 'PinLayout'
    pod 'FlexLayout'
    pod 'LayoutKit'
    pod 'PromiseKit/Alamofire'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
end


target 'XXX' do
    pod 'Reveal-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']
end


target 'XXX share extension' do
   inherit! :search_paths
end
```

Edited to add screenshots:

[image: Embedded binaries and linked frameworks screenshot]

[image: Embed frameworks screenshot]

Comment: Please share you podfile

Comment: And you shouldent have to explicendly define a path for each pod, Cocoapods should deal with that for you. Only in cases the library requests a special setup this should have done.

Comment: @MCMatan I didn't think I should have to add these pods explicitly, apart from Reveal, which does have that specific requirement. But I don't know why Cocoapods isn't doing it for me correctly, or what else I'm missing that stops the app from building otherwise.

Comment: It seems you are trying to build CocoaLumberjack as a framework and it does not exist. Can you please add an image of your "Linked frameworks and libraries" and "Embedded Libraries"

Comment: Strange, do you have "Embed Frameworks" too?

Comment: Oh and try to change Pods.framework  to required and not optional

Comment: @MCMatan Not sure where you mean about changing Pods.framework to required? In Linked Frameworks and Libraries it's already set to required. I also tried setting it to optional there earlier but that made no difference so I set it back to required. Is there another spot I should try changing it?

Comment: Sorry! Optional, and not required. Mmm the most suspicious thing to me is the line: "Referenced from: [path removed]" I do not understand how can a path be removed. Did you recently update from an old version? Did you use pod update? What version of this library are you using? Anyway, It's better to practice to specify a version...

Comment: Also, try to clean cash, and driven data, and remove app before reinstalling it

Comment: @MCMatan Oh sorry! I removed the path there when I pasted in the details. It actually lists the path in the console when I see the error. You're right that I should specify the version of the pod in my Podfile.

I tried removing the app before running it, since I had tried everything else you mentioned, but it made no difference. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I ended up undoing the manual search paths and working from the original error instead, since I couldn't get this fixed.